# Question with an accepted and upvoted answer in 'Unanswered' tag

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

I have detected what seems to me a bug:

[image]

I have repeatedly clicked on the tag 'Unanswered' but the first question is still there and seems very much answered (and upvoted). What's happening?

Comment: [Caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com)